# Formatting Data into Chart C# WPF

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, charts

I have a database where a user can select a date range and pull the data back. This is saved into three columns, Date, Time, Value. if it's temperature it's a Line Chart, if it's a Meter it's Bar Chart.

I have the below code but it's not working, I'm getting confused how to send this data.

Setting different values:

```
eChartType chartType = eChartType.ColumnClustered;

if (plotName.Contains("temp") || plotName.Contains("Temp"))
{
    chartType = eChartType.Line;
}

var chart = worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.AddChart($"{plotName} Chart", chartType);

var label = worksheet.Cells["A2:B2571"];
var values = worksheet.Cells["C2:C2571"];

chart.Chart.Series.Add(label, values);

chart.Chart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;
```

Throwing all information into bottom area of chart and not in chart.

Comment: So what is your question exactly ?
What are you trying to achieve ?
What errors are you getting from this code ?How exactly does it not work ?

Answer (score -2):

You should try something different like this:

//not chart type you should change it.
//change var to int and chart to double or float as you will wish 
// again change var into int and worksheet is equal to ToString in C# then take off the string "" and change the : to referring after that you should just change 3 main things

// change chart to double or float suggesting float here because of the complex 
// Chart is not good!!!! you can get the position in many different ways just set a .point = new Location (X,Y) then just set it twice and not once